# Encoded PHP captcha?

Tags: javascript, python, php, html, captcha

While web scraping I needed to bypass captcha, but it no ordinary captcha. It was encoded with reserved characters looked gibberish. I couldn't find this kind of technique anywhere else.

*captcha_new.php*

``` ����JFIF``��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default quality ��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!........ ```(continues few lines)

but in the browser, it rendered as an image.

[image]

I'm really confused what is this and how this works.

Comment: Perhaps it is designed to stop people programtically bypassing it - for some reason?

Comment: you are trying to open source code of image, try to call that file in img tags

Comment: May be its just a pict with intentionally wrong extension. Have you tried to name it with jpg extension and open with standard  image viewer?

Comment: its created probably via gd library, very easy to bypass, just google image to text free service out there, you'll never bypass it the way you're doing right now

Comment: I tried changing extention, opening in tag, decoding characters nothing made sense.

Comment: The image is generated server side, you will always get gibberish client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an image.

You can can see it by the "JFIF" and creator information. (And you would perhaps see it by the mime type in the http transfer encoding if viewed in delevoper tools of your web browser.)

What's confusing you is the .php file extension. But this doesn't mean to much except that this image was most probably *generated* by a php script. (So to be clear: *this is not* a php script! You don't download php scripts. The server excutes them and sends you their results.)

Answer (score -2):

It's php stream with binary content.

For get image use function `file_get_content()`.

Example:

```
$content = file_get_content("http://example.com/captcha_new.php");

// and put variable in your readable function
// or save file for access in localhost

file_put_content(...)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php